# Linux for loop function in .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have the following alias set up in ~/.bashrc. It prints data from some sensors connected to a server. I'd like to condense this into a for loop, but cannot get the loop to run successfully. The non-loop syntax I have working is below. `vd` is an executable on this server that prints data. Here I have arguments to print 5 lines of data `-n5` from a specific sensor `-s ${scylpres[n]}`, then filter the output so it only prints lines with the "," delimiter `cut -d',' -s -f1-`.

```
scylpres=($(eproms | grep -i 'trtl' | grep -i 'cylinder pressure' | cut -d',' -f3));
alias cylpres='vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[0]} | cut -d',' -s -f1- &&
vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[1]} | cut -d',' -s -f1- && vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[2]} | cut -d',' -s -f1- && vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[3]} | cut -d',' -s -f1- &&
vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[4]} | cut -d',' -s -f1- && vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[5]} | cut -d, -s -f1-';
```

I am struggling to wrap this into a for loop. I've tried:

```
i=0;
function cpres {
for i in {0..${scylpres[@]}}
do
vd -n5 -s ${scylpres${i}} | cut -d',' -s -f1-
done
};
```

And:

```
start=0;
stop=${scylpres[@]};
function cpres {
for((i=$start;i<=$end;i++))
do
vd -n5 -s ${scylpres[$((i++))]} | cut -d',' -s -f1-
done
};
```

And have tried different versions of the i call in both of these. For example, `${scylpres[$i]}`,`${scylpres[$(i)]}`, `${scylpres$[((i++))]}`
But, all I'm seeing is my command line go to `>` .

Comment: Have you tried using the "-x" and / or "-v" flags to get the shell to tell you what it is doing?

Comment: The `{1..10}` [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) notation is extremely limited and can't take a variable like you're trying to use — variables aren't expanded until long after brace expansion is complete.  Maybe you need to use `seq` instead?

Comment: Thanks, all. shellcheck.net helped tremendously. Solution involved declaring scylpres as an array before it showed up in the loop. That, and using double quotes around variables :   `scylpres=($(eproms | grep -i 'ecse' | grep -i 'cylinder pressure'| cut -d, -s -f3));
declare -a scylpres
start=0;
stop="${#scylpres[@]}";
function ecsecylpres {
for((i=start;i<=stop;i++))
do
 vd -n5 -s "${scylpres[${i}]}" | cut -d',' -s -f1-
done
};`